# Why file activity instrument is not working for ios

Tags: xcode, file, instruments

I wanted to check the file activity in my app using the "File Activity" instrument template, but I guess it's restraint to the mac os platform.

My question is why? it doesn't make any sense to me to not enable it for iOS

Comment: What do you mean by `file activity`?

Comment: File Activity - Records open, close and stats operations